# A bunch of bootstrap classes or create a custom css class in master css?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I work at a big company and at this company we put everything into 1 massive css file. I've noticed that this master CSS file has grown 5000 lines in the past 6 months. In this case, is it better to use several bootstrap classes (max. 10) or continue to add custom classes even though bootstrap is available?

This is an example of something created with only bootstrap:

```
<div class="col-auto d-flex align-items-center text-center pl-3 pr-1 text-secondary">
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. These type of questions are off-topic. This question is too subjective. *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."* Please read: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should break up the big css file into components and use a build process

Answer (score 0):

Being a Frontend developer working on a big product with a big team and have **same scenarios** as you have i.e **one massive CSS** file and **twitter bootstrap** and still under development.

Based on these I am sharing the way how I managed instead of explaining the concept of **Object Oriented** CSS (OOCSS), **Scalable and Modular Architecture** for CSS(SMACSS), Don't Repeat Yourself CSS (DRY CSS).

Let’s take a look what should be there in custom css file.

**A) Major layout** rules are for the major components of a site like the header, footer, sidebar, or main- content. 
**B) Minor layout** components are considered as modules and typically live inside the major layout components. A content box inside a sidebar is an example.

**Eg.** gray-box,light-box,white-box,bg-widget,icon-widget,tabset etc.

Now for theming of  a website you would only need these two things **Major layout** and **Minor layout** but if you don’t require to follow this structure or need changes not integral part of this structure go for *twitter bootstrap* classes.
This approach is pretty simple and **reusable for Backend team** as they just copy and paste the markup.